# Web API not working with existing MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, webapi

If I create standalone webAPI project It is working fine. I am trying to configure webAPI in existing MVC project. I have done following steps.

- Create WebApiConfig class and done necessary configuration
- Registered the configuration in Global.ascx

URL: localhost/myApp/api/Values
Response: 404 not found